# Can molten Strontium and Barium Hydroxides be electrolysed to give the metals?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

Can strontium and barium hydroxides be electrolysed to give the metals? I've noticed they have relatively low melting points. What challenges would this present?

Comment: They contain hydrogen and the hydrogen is reduced, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @Oscar Lanzi comment: first, all the hydrogen (and half the oxygen) would be electrolyzed before then alkaline earth metals.  At that point, **if kept liquid**, then the $\ce{BaO}$ and $\ce{SrO}$ remaining would be split. That would not be easy, as the [melting point of $\ce{BaO}$ is 2,196 K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barium_oxide) and [that of $\ce{SrO}$ is 2,804K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strontium_oxide) (though a eutectic mix of the oxides would be a bit lower).

[It's more efficient to dissolve the oxides in a halide salt. The electrolysis of $\ce{CaO}$ in $\ce{CaCl2}$ has been explored [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/287763437_Electrolysis_of_CaO_in_the_molten_CaCl2_for_direct_reduction_of_TiO2) and [here.](http://www.lm-foundation.or.jp/english/abstract-vol44/abstract/01.html)